# Why is the past perfect tense not used with the event that occurred first in this sentence?

Tags: past-perfect

In the book *A history of modern Europe* by John M. Merriman, it is mentioned "After the collapse of the Roman Empire, Christendom had been split between the Roman Catholic Church and the Eastern Orthodox Church following the Great Schism between the two churches in 1054."

**Why did the author use the past perfect tense in the second clause instead of the first one as the collapse of the Roman Empire occurred before the great schism?**

Comment: I'm guessing that the author is talking about events that happened some time after the Great Schism.  From the point of view of those events, the Schism was in the past, so he explains about it using the perfect tense.

Comment: There must be sentences before and after this one with verbs in the past but later in time to the split. By itself, we don't need *had been split*.

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said. I can't locate the source online, but it's a racing certainty that *surrounding / following* text will be focused on some time ***after*** the split.

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to give more of the surrounding context. I'm voting to close for now as unclear. Note, the sentence itself is a bit confusing about the timeline even if it's valid. The split was "following" the Great Schism, but was also "after" the fall of Rome (by a lot, if the author means 476 CE). Both are true, but it's odd to talk about them out of order.

Comment: What is the next sentence in the book?

Comment: The next sentence is " The claim by the bishop of Rome—the pope—to authority over all Eastern Christians (as well as a festering doctrinal dispute over the nature of the Holy Trinity) led to the break, culminating in the pope’s excommunication of the patriarch of Constantinople."

Comment: @BOLA123: Unless there's a leap forward in time in subsequent sentences in that paragraph, I think you're right to question the choice of past perfect there.  Simple past "**was** split" would have been fine, and then in the subsequent sentence "**had led** to the break".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "had split" sets the temporal focus to a time later than the split, and suggests that the writer is then going to talk about some later events.

This is a common way of using the construction, particularly in stories (If a story starts "John's alarm hadn't woken him and he had had to rush his shower and breakfast", you know that the story is going to be set later in the day) but also in other kinds of narrative.

Comment: Thanks alot Mr Colin Fine, that answered my question. the author did talk about some later events and explained why the schism happened.

Comment: (Though it's more likely that *preceding* context has clarified that temporal focus, since that unprepared *in media res* approach is less likely in a history textbook than in fiction.)

Comment: @AndyBonner  Your point has validity but I think the past perfect can be used to set the temporal context in a history,  as the boundary between history and story is often blurry.

Comment: @TimR You mean like as in the historical account "Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire"? :-) (Present perfect, but still...)

Comment: But the writer goes on to speak of some *earlier* events.